# Updating index in Lucene.NET

Tags: lucene.net

I am doing a POC on Search using Lucene.NET.

I fire a stored procedure which fetches around 50000 records from the database.
Thses records I put in the Lucene Index.

Now when the records in database changes, how to update the Lucene index.
Deleting the entire previous indexed and creating a new one will take a lot of time.

I want to append the new records from the database to the existing index.

How can I achieve this.
Any ideas ???

Thanks,
Aneesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use lucene AddDocument method, something like this :

```
IndexWriter iw = new IndexWriter(folder, GetAnalyzer(), false);
  try
  {
    Document luceneDoc = new Document();
    /// add fields to the lucene document
    iw.AddDocument(luceneDoc);
  }
  finally
  {
    iw.Close();
  }
```

Comment: I did this, But i get an error at this 
IndexWriter iw = new IndexWriter(folder, GetAnalyzer(), false);
(When the third in param in above function is false)

no segments* file found in Lucene.Net.Store.SimpleFSDirectory
@D:\Lucene.Net\Data\Publication lockFactory=Lucene.Net.Store.SimpleFSLockFactory: files: write.lock

Comment: do you have lock file in your index directory ?

Comment: Hi Antonio, I think u guessed it right.

I get this error.

Lock obtain timed out: SimpleFSLock@D:\Lucene.Net\Data\Publication\write.lock

How to solve this ?

Comment: you didn't close IndexWrite last time you build index, must put that in finally block. Try simply delete lock file, but maybe your index is corrupted now

Comment: I did close it. How to delete lock file? Do u mean, the one which is kept in the folder where index is stored

Comment: yes that one. Now you have 2 problems, one is how this happened, usually reason is indexwriter not being closed. You should check your code. And second problem is that in your current index directory there is a lock file and lucene thinks that some other process is writing to index, so you must delete that lock manually